# Run query results with CTE to create automatically a table with possibility to refresh created table on a daily basis in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, common-table-expression, create-table

I have the below query that run in BigQuery. I am using CTEs to define the tables A and B which are then joined and queried.
I am happy with the results I am getting but would like to add components into the query that would save the results automatically in a new table in a desired location. With a potential solution, what are the options to refresh the newly created table automatically on a daily basis?

```
With A as (

select 

   atb.some_thing as a_field,
   atb.somethingelse as a_otherfield
   from `project.dataset.atable` AS atb
),

B AS (

 select 
 bt.some_thing as b_field
 from `project.dataset.btable` AS bt
)

select 
    A.a_field,  
    A.a_otherfield,
    B.b_field
  from A 
  left join B on A.a_field = B.b_field
```

Comment: Probably the easiest and cheapest solution would be to create a view.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Does that mean the view gets updated when the underlying tables refresh?

Comment: The view is actually just a saved query, so the output will change if your input data changes!

Comment: Thanks @rtenha for your reply.